# Is there an R function for rounding based on the size of the number?

Tags: r, rounding, significant-digits

I want the rounding of a set of numbers to automatically change as the numbers get larger. I am making barplot labels. Here is what currently shows up:

```
<39 
39 to 11564 
11564 to 23090 
23090 to 50893 
50893 to 89034 
89034 to 138900 
138900 to 183562
```

I think the number 39 is important, that is, I do not want to apply round() to all of the numbers equally because I do not want to change 39 to 40. I am writing a function so I need something that will adjust the amount it rounds based on the size of the number.

Ideal rounding:

```
<39 .         ( when 2 or 3 digits long, do not round) 
39 to 11600    ( when 5 digits long, round to 3 places) 
11600 to 23000  
23000 to 50900
50900 to 89000
89000 to 139000 ( when 6 digits long, round to 4 places)
139000 to 184000
```

does this already exist, where I can specify rounding by length? Or should I just write my own helper function to try to do this separately.

Thanks for the help!
Best, Tessa

Comment: You can generally control your cuts and/or boundaries, and it sounds like the `signif` function might come in handy.

Comment: `signif(c(39, 11564, 23090, 50893, 89034, 138900, 183562), 3)`

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly.

Comment: just cleaning up the number representation. the question doesn't really need much - I think it's quite clear without the edits. just trying to move it out of the queue.